# Script Versioning

Tags: powershell, version-control, versioning

I am working on a very large script and I stumbled across one issue already, how can I version the scripts? (ex) superscript.ps1 is on version 2 but if a user is using version 1 of the script it will notify them during the initialization of the script.

basically I can't restrict where they are pulling it from, so I thought about keeping a "CurrentVersion" File on one of our servers and keep the version number in it but how could I get the running script to check that file and error out?

```
CurrentVersion.txt
superscript1, 2.0
superscript2, 2.5
script1, 10.2
```

I just can't find what would be a plausible way of actually implementing something like this, any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly I think the way to go here is to stop doing development in the central folder where the production version of your script lives.

Start using git, do development on local machines or dev boxes or something, in a new branch. Merge to master when you're done and either copy master to the central location or pull it from a centralized repo (GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab).

Comment: See now I thought of this but the issue is I work off my local machine during the bulk of my development and save it to a central location after it gets moved to Prod, but then users copy and run it from their local machine and then have no idea when it gets updated and ends up using old versions.

Comment: @Luke I guess you could make the script check for git being installed on the machine, and throw an exception if it doesn't. Then from there, it can `git pull` or at least check for it being up to date or not. Sounds janky to me. Another idea, put the real meat of the code in a script module, then `Import-Module \\server\share\scripts\module.psm1 -ErrorAction Stop`, then the updates to the code get done in the module? To be fair, this sounds like a personnel problem. :-/

Comment: @Luke Is there an actual problem with users running older versions? As long as your scripts are compatible with each other (which would be guaranteed when you use a single repository for them), then users should be free to run whatever version they want…

Comment: @briantist that might be what I have to do, or maybe I follow Poke and just don't care what version they are using but only help them if they are using the most current. Thanks for your help